# nvme SSD problems - Cannot format - HDPARM permision denied

Tags: partitioning, ssd, format, nvme, hdparm

My Kingston 240G SSD has suffered some strange errors. While it had Windows 10 installed on it, it just reset to previous state after every re-boot (meaning no file changes whatsoever, uninstalled programs were back, deleted file were back, and new files gone).

I installed Ubuntu on HDD and tried to format the SSD using Drives. I get the error: `Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object(udisks-error-quark,0).

Installed GSmartControl and tried to run a diagnostic. This is most I can get out of it.

```
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       KINGSTON SA1000M8240G
Serial Number:                      50026B76827B4716
Firmware Version:                   E8FK11.R
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x2646
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x0026b7
Total NVM Capacity:                 240.057.409.536 [240 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      0
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          240.057.409.536 [240 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            0026b7 6827b47165
Local Time is:                      Fri Jun 19 01:17:38 2020 EEST
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0007):   Security Format Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x001e):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     84 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     88 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.90W  0.0790W       -    0  0  0  0      600     600
 1 +     7.90W  0.0790W       -    0  0  0  0      600     600
 2 +     7.90W  0.0790W       -    0  0  0  0      600     600
 3 -   0.1000W  0.0790W       -    3  3  3  3     1000    1000
 4 -   0.0050W  0.0790W       -    4  4  4  4   400000   90000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         1
 1 -    4096       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

Also tried some finally, i tried some HDPARM commands (im new and have no ideea), but they returned with `permission denied`.

Was wondering if my SSD is just broken (turn in for warranty) or if there is some software / firmware problem that can be fixed. Anyone had similar problems? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This definitely seems like a hardware issue, but if you'd still like to try formatting it, then I recommend using `mkfs`. In order to do this, you need to open up a terminal (Ctl+Alt+T or search in applications menu). Run the following `fdisk` command, and pay close attention to the size of each device. You should be looking for a device that is roughly 240GB, and it should be an actual device (not a loop), which should look like `/dev/sdX`, where 'X' is the letter of the drive. The second line of the blocks should identify the `Disk Model`, and your SSD will likely say `KINGSTON SA1000M8240G`. I'll refer to the corresponding device as `/dev/sdX` from now on, and just make sure to replace the 'X' with the proper letter.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In order to format the drive, you'll either use `mkfs.ext4` if you plan to use it for Linux, or `mkfs.ntfs` for Windows. Alternatively, if you plan to use it as an external drive, I suppose you could format it to FAT32 with `mkfs.fat -F 32`. I'll list each of these commands for you below

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX

sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdX

sudo mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdX
```

If you run into an issue describing the device being mounted, simply unmount the drive.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX
```

You shouldn't run into permission errors here, but let me know if you do, and I'll try to figure out how to approach the problem from a different angle. If your SSD still has problems after a format, then it's probably best to send it in for warranty.

Comment: ```Creating filesystem with 58607766 4k blocks and 14655488 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 081c2488-9626-4367-b2a8-e10a2eec4adf
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
 32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
 4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: mkfs.ext4: No data available while writing out and closing file system```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that final line `No data available while writing out and closing file system`. I'm assuming that means that there was an error in the finalization? I'd then assume that the format didn't work properly, and if so, did it still reset again like it did previously? You could also paste outputs into a pastebin and link them so you don't have to deal with the comment length limit.

Comment: Yep, It booted Windows just fine after that command! Some more internet digging and found out I should use nvme-cli for the job. Here is the Smart-log I got using nvme-cli. From what i can tell it says that the SSD is in good shape. https://pastebin.com/raw/gsm2Spa9

Comment: I'm not really sure what else to do in terms of formatting it. I think that you will probably have to call about sending it in for warranty and explaining what's happening to the representative. If it _is_ a firmware issue, they should already know about it. I suppose you could see if anyone else has any ideas about what to do. I'm not that familiar with very low level operations, but I think if there is a way to fix it, it's gonna be at a very low level.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! At this point is more bout of an unanswered question of what is actually happening then is the loss of the SSD. There is also the question of submitting an un-formatable partition with almost 2 years worth of data for warranty.

Comment: The only other thing I could even think of is just writing 0s over the entire drive, but I feel like you'd have the same issue. if you want to try, it might take a few minutes, but you can just do `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M status=progress`. Again, I'm not sure that it'll change anything though. I'm not really sure what the actual problem is. It seems like somehow the SSD is acing as volatile memory, so every time it powers off, it resets to a default.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/xdSWpq0H

Comment: Yeah, I figured the same thing would happen again. I'm curious to see if anyone else has a better idea of what's going on in terms of the hardware and/or software. It's really a strange scenario, because it seems like nothing is actually getting written to the nand flash on the SSD, or that it all somehow flips back after a power cycle. It reminds me of the way that bootable USBs work with ISOs, except it even resets after a format. I'd really like to know what's actually going on with it, because I've never personally dealt with an SSD issue quite like this.

Comment: Secondarily, if you're worried about data security, then yeah, I'd definitely be hesitant to send in a drive I couldn't delete anything off of too. The good thing is that you can still easily make a backup of the data currently on the drive, so you shouldn't have to worry about losing your data. The bad thing, of course, is if you had personal info like banking information on the drive. I'd assumed you'd made a backup before trying to format it, but I guess I never asked if you had.